# How do I access the same database from different activities?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing an app and I want to store the high scores. I have it working  to show the high score on the end activity. However, I want to have a highscores activity to show all the highscores. I am doing this by, in the highscores activity, calling the end activity to return the high score, so the database doesn't change. After running a debug, I saw that it got to the databasehandler but got caught on getReadableDatabase(), saying that it was unable to invoke the method on a null object reference.

This is my highscores method(I didn't include the whole thing, and the ifs are because there are different difficulties of the game)

```
public class highscores extends Activity {
TextView mode, score;
Button right, back;
int modenum;
end get=new end();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_highscores);
    mode =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.scorebar);
    score =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    right =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);
    back =(Button)findViewById(R.id.highscores);
    mode.setText("Easy");
    score.setText(get.datatostring(1));
    modenum =1;
}
public void right(View view){
    if(modenum==1) {
        modenum = 2;
        mode.setText("Hard");
        score.setText(get.datatostring(2));
    }else if(modenum==2) {
        modenum = 3;
        mode.setText("X-Mode");
        score.setText(get.datatostring(3));
    }else {
        modenum = 1;
        mode.setText("Easy");
        score.setText(get.datatostring(1));
    }
}
```

This is in the end method

```
    public String datatostring(int difficulty){
    MyDBHandler db = new MyDBHandler(this, null,null,1);
    return db.datatostring(difficulty);
}
```

And this is in the databasehandler

```
        public String datatostring(int difficulty){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String dbString = "";
        String c;
        if(difficulty==1)
            c = COLUMN_SCORE;
        else if(difficulty==2)
            c = COLUMN_HARD;
        else
        c = COLUMN_X;
        String query = "SELECT "+c+" FROM "+TABLE_SCORES;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(c);
            String value = cursor.getString(index);
            if(value!=null){
                dbString += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(c));
            }
        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return dbString;
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented the database access using a SQLiteManager class which contains a private SQLiteHelper class?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` to handle this.

You should see this example:
[Android Sqlite DB](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)

Hope that helps, i personally works in this way.

The other option is to use som ORM, i recommend to use `GreenDao`, its good, and lets handle easy way this kind of actions.

Regards.

Comment: I tried using this example but I get errors when trying to use it in multiple places in my application. Any idea how to use this method in multiple activities? @Max Pinto

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

But as you see you have no clear concept of the connection.

Bd in the android is SQLite (recommendation) Always be on the same route, you need to create a class that allows you to manage and connect to the database. The class will be SQLiteOpenHelper

Check [THIS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

You can connect one or more times to the database, since activity A, B or activity you want.

The important thing is to define the handler to connect, close, make request to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) tutorial to create a concurrent and scalable database

Remember :

1. You should always make database queries through one instance (Singleton) of your database adapter else you will face a lot of issues when accessing your database concurrently from different classes.
2. Use `SQLiteOpenHelper` class for accessing your database. As it gives you many useful functions eg. upgrading user's database when you publish app updates with schema changes.